# Read syscall in NASM does not stop after reaching to a newline character when the input is redirected from a file, not terminal

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, system-calls, tty

The following assembly code is supposed to read two separate strings in two different lines; and sure enough, it does work properly when the input is given by the user via terminal:

```
section .bss
    str1    resb    100
    str2    resb    100
    
section .text
    global _start
    
_start:
    ;Reading the first string
    mov rax,    3
    mov rbx,    0
    mov rcx,    str1
    mov rdx,    100
    int 0x80
    
    ;Reading the second string
    mov rax,    3
    mov rbx,    0
    mov rcx,    str2
    mov rdx,    100
    int 0x80

Exit:
    mov rax,    1
    mov rbx,    0
    int 0x80
```

To run this program (saved in a file named `a.asm`), I run the following commands in terminal:

```
nasm -f elf64 ./a.asm
ld -o ./a -e _start ./a.o
./a
```

It reads two strings in two lines and halts. But when I set an input file such as `input.txt`, it does not read the second string; the whole file content is read by the first read system call. The contents of `input.txt`:

```
Hello1
Hello2
```

To set the input file via terminal, I use the following command:

```
./a < input.txt
```

The problem, as I understand it, is that when the program is reading from a file, the read system call does not stop when it reaches the `\n` character and only stops when it reaches the `NULL` character at the end of the file: So reading only one string is not a problem.

I have tried replacing the `\n` character with `\r`, but did not work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: That's because your input is not line buffered. Also note `read` may return even less than a complete line. Write code that works in either mode, such as by using a single buffer that you fill via multiple reads until you get two lines in it.

Comment: If you can use the C library it already has stdio written for you :)

Comment: `./a < input.txt` redirects the input from a regular file, not a terminal.  Opposite of what I thought your question title was saying.  It's the terminal itself (in "cooked" mode with line editing) that makes input available when you hit EOL (newline) or EOF (control-D), in the default `stty` settings.  Not the newline character itself in the input stream.

Comment: You can't "fix" this; Unix I/O isn't naturally structured into lines, that's just a TTY thing.  You have to parse the block of bytes you read, looking for the `\n` yourself.  (And if you don't see two newlines, keep reading more bytes if you're not at EOF; the file might have long lines, or no `0xa` bytes at all.)  `0xa` isn't special *at all* for `read` system calls.

Comment: BTW, if you run `cat` on one terminal and attach `strace -p $(pidof cat)` from another terminal window, you can see what happens when you type stuff and then hit ctrl-D to submit instead of newline.

Comment: There's no "NULL character" (or ASCII NUL `'\0'`) at the end of a file.  Files are binary, with a length and arbitrary contents.  There can be `00` bytes anywhere, and not necessarily at the end.  That's why `write` takes a pointer+length, not a 0-terminated C string.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the valuable information. I am trying to design a judge that runs the students' codes by itself. I am concluding, from the comments, that I cannot fix this by writing a bash script or even a python code to solve this. (A piece of code that runs the assembly code and giving it input just like a user.)

Comment: @Shayan Nope.  And if the student's code expects each read system call to produce one line of input, it is defective anyway.  That is one of the reasons why I strongly recommend to just use the libc when programming in assembly.  Call `fgets` or any other standard IO function and it works just fine.

Comment: Oh, if you want to script code with its input coming from a TTY, you actually *can* do that.  It's what GNU `expect` does (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect), using a pseudo-tty (pty).  Programs like `xterm` and `screen` also use a pty to programmatically control the other end of a terminal that something is running on, often `bash`.  Usually xterm just sends along ASCII characters in response to X events like keypresses, but it is doing it manually and can do stuff like paste.

Comment: So if you want your students to write programs that make assumptions about the input being from a terminal in order to delimit separate input lines, then yeah you could do that as a simplified non-robust "toy" interface.  Maybe at some point you teach then why this happened to work, if there's time to go over the Unix system-call and terminal semantics, otherwise as @fuz says maybe better not to start with a "toy program only" way of doing things.